# NumPy - fast-compact serializing (to bytes) arrays of popular dtypes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, serialization, hash

I have an array `a` that may be of any popular `dtype`, including `np.str_` or any standard Python type (stored as `np.object_`).

The task is to convert `a` to (and from) bytes ([serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)) so that:

1. Each array's element is represented as variable amount of bytes that is invertible, i.e. given bytes of an element it should be possible to exactly restore element back. In other words each element should be possible to serialize and de-serialize.
2. Serialization function should process whole array at once.
3. Serialization should be as fast as possible.
4. Also preferably compact, so that each element produces close to minimal length of sequence of bytes to be still de-serializable.
5. Serialization should produce total compact sequence of bytes containing all subsequences (for each element) and information about theirs sizes. E.g. one good way is just to concatenate serialized bytes of each element plus provide another array having all lengths of sub-sequences.
6. Serialization should support all popular `dtype`s including `np.str_` and all Python standard types (stored as `np.object_` dtype).
7. De-serialization function should be available too.
8. Would be great if such serialization function is available inside numpy library or implemented using numpy functions.

Why is this needed? One current application is that I want to hash my huge numpy array of popular dtypes. Each element should produce one integer hash. This should be fast and collision resistant, i.e. different elements should produce almost unique hashes, any sub-bits of hash should be collision resistant too. We should assume that hash function can process just sequences of bytes.

For achieving this requested serialization function is needed. [Collision resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance) and fast [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is already given.

Comment: Be aware that the value of an `object` element will only be valid for the current memory layout.  If you try to recreate the array in a different session, that reference will be different.  `numeric` and `str` dtypes can be serialized, `object` cannot.  A `np.save` of an array contains `pickled` versions of all objects.

Comment: @hpaulj I mean that we should have serialization function to for any possible object type, but just for standard python types stored as `np.object_`, like list/dict/int/float/str/bytes, or any nested combination of them. All these standard types should be serialized fast. Of cause in general `pickle` can be used, but is there a possibility to have optimized for speed serialization at least for all common types.

Comment: `list` and `dict` store references to Python objects in any degree of nesting.  I suspect `pickle` is the most general serialization tool.  `json` can handle a restricted subset of these (it's a restricted subset of `javascript` arrays).